# Create child Component after Observable data is available

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular 5 app which just renders a component

```
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild(TestComponent) testElement: Testcomponent;
}
```

But this child component needs some infos (e.g. there is config for additional created subcomponents) 
The config is loaded from an external source (rest), so i have created an `http.get` request and wrapped it in an rxjs Observable

In my AppComponent I have therefor a `Observable<string>` where i can subscribe to.
My `TestComponent` basically is not able to show anything before the config is available - so my question is how I can wait with the initialization/rendering of the component until the Rest-Response is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)** Directive to instantiate the child-component after the subscription is resolved or when data is Available.

**Component-1**

```
 public response$:Observable<Idata[]>;
    constructor(public service:ShareService)
      {
          this.response$= this.service.getdata();

      }
```

**Component-1 Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="response$">
<hello [response]="response$"></hello>
</ng-container>
```

**Component-2**

```
export class HelloComponent  {
@Input() response:Observable<Idata[]>


}
```

**Component-2 Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (response|async)">
  {{item.body}}
<div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2tnus)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by tapping in to the life cycle hook `OnInit` and having the child component take inputs with the `async` pipe.

**Example**

```
// parent component
export class MyParent implements OnInit {
  myObservable$: Observable<any>;
  ngOnInit() {
    //do whatever you need to get observable.
  }
}
//parent html
<my-child [data]="myObservable$ | async"></my-child>

//child component
export class MyChild {
  @Input() data: //whatever data type it is
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: but in my child component's html I have `*ngFor="let subcomponent of data.subcomponents;"` - and now i get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subcomponents' of null    --> it seems like it's not initalized yet...

Comment: you need to adjust my snippet to your needs. I have no idea what your data is and you'll have to figure that part out on your own. This is enough to get you there at least your child can see the data