# How to use NgFor on Observable using Async Pipe to generate Child Component after data is loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am facing an issue while trying to render a child component using data from a Observable from it's parent, and after that, using `async pipe` to convert the data to a list objects and render it using *NgFor. I did:

1. **Generate Observable Data in Parent Component**:

   ```js
   // Parent Component
   dataSet$!: Observable<Data[]>;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.dataSet$ = this.serviceData.getData();
   }
   ```
2. **Send Data from Parent to Child Using Async Pipe**:

   ```html
   <!-- Parent Component Template -->
   <ng-container *ngIf="dataSet$ | async as dataSet">
     <app-row-data-list *ngFor="let data of dataSet" [data]="data"></app-row-data-list>
   </ng-container>
   ```
3. **Child Component with @Input Property**:

   ```js
   // Child Component
   export class RowDataListComponent {
     @Input() data!: Data;
   }
   ```

However, the data is not being rendered as expected. The child components do not appear.

---

What I tried so far is the fixes mentioned in the following answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76025282/8297745
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586048/8297745
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599001/8297745

But I was'nt able to fix it using those. I also searched a lot.
Actually, I'm a couple of hours on this so if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit**: With help from the answer here, I was able to fix it.
I did as follows (Look in Stack Blitz example):

https://angular-child-parent-communication-example-uxz7dg.stackblitz.io

Comment: please share the data sample from API and if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your exact code but here you can see a working exapmple:

```
interface Item {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

type Items = Item[];

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class DataService {
  private http = inject(HttpClient);

  getData() {
    return this.http.get<Items>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <pre>{{item() | json}}</pre>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [JsonPipe],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  item = input<Item>();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <app-child *ngFor="let data of (data$ | async)" [item]="data"></app-child>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [ChildComponent, NgFor, AsyncPipe],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  private dataService = inject(DataService);

  data$ = this.dataService.getData().pipe(startWith([]), share());
}

bootstrapApplication(App, { providers: [provideHttpClient()] });
```

**See** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vs7fhu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just did a little different. Edited my question so you can check it out, it reflects the scenarion on my actual application.